# element not placed on desired location : class="ten columns" has no effect on the place of the element

Tags: html, web2py

According to web2py documentation page is divided in sixteen columns and this should be placed on 10th column but it does not work, I am new to all these so have no idea where to start debugging from. pointers?

```
 <div class="ten columns">
      <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

`ten columns` has no effect. The list is placed on default location(left most).

`*Entire File*`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Web On Steroids</title>
    {{response.files.append(URL('static','css/skelton.css'))}}
    {{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
  </head>
<body>
  <header class="container">
    <div class="ten columns">
      <h1>tukker.me</h1>
      </div>
    <div class="ten columns">
      <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  <section id="main" class="container">
    <div class="ten columns">
          <h1>Messages With 300 Chars</h1>
      </div>
  <div class="sixteen columns">
        <a href="#" class="button">Register</a>
      </div>
      <footer class="container">
      <nav class="sixteen columns alpha omega">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
     </nav>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know how to phrase the question, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: post a demo or use jsfiddle.net to create something we can work with

Comment: @Huangism web2py is not supported on jsfiddle.net I can upload the whole thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using the web2py scaffolding app, which currently uses [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) for the responsive grid. It may help to review the [Skeleton documentation](http://getskeleton.com/#grid).

Note, `class="ten columns"` does not put the content in the tenth column, it makes the div ten columns wide. If you want something in the tenth column, you should either precede it with a div that is nine columns wide (i.e., `class="nine columns"`), or offset it with `class="one column offset-by-nine"` (actually, you probably want it wider than just one column, which is only 40px wide). Note, within a given row, the total number of columns (including offset columns) should add up to no more than 16. Specifically, in your case, you might try:

```
  <header class="container">
    <div class="nine columns">
      <h1>tukker.me</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="one column">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

That will put your h1 header in the first nine columns and your nav ul in the tenth column (to the right of the h1). If you want the nav ul to be more than one column (40px) wide, just specify its class with the number of columns you want (e.g., `class="four columns"`). Note, because the h1 div takes up 9 of the 16 available columns, the nav div should not be more than 7 columns wide, otherwise, it will get pushed down below the h1 instead of being floated to the right of it (that is what was happening when you had it set to be 10 columns wide).